# Variable with functions in variable

Tags: javascript

I am having a question about javascript. To get my code organized I have the functions gathered in one variable like this.

```
var helper = new function(){
    this.writeProp = function(){
       //write the property
    }
    this.getProp = function(){
       //get property
    }
    this.updateProp = function(){
       //get property
    }
}
```

So far the code is working but and I can call it with `helper.getProp()`
Now the amount of functions are getting bigger so I want to call the functions like this `helper.prop.get()`
How can I accomplish this?

My thought was the following but it's not working.

```
var helper = new function(){
    var prop = new function(){
       this.write = function(){
           //write the property
        }
        this.getProp = function(){
           //get property
        }
        this.updateProp = function(){
           //get property
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the right way to do it? Or should I not try to organize my code this way?

Comment: return `prop` after all. You'll get every function  in `prop`. As `prop` is private variable inside your function and you can not access private variable from your function.

Comment: I'm sorry could you post a codesample. I cannot understand it from the sentense. Thank you :)

Comment: @Slive2611 Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/esgagaqx/

Comment: Is there a reason you use `new function` instead of simply `{ ... }`?

Comment: Is ist better to use {}? How would the code look like?

Comment: If what you have there is a singleton object, then yes, there is absolutely no reason to use `new function`. See: [Joachim Pileborg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34135013/697154).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why `helper` *or* `helper.prop` should be functions. Why not objects, like

```
var helper = {
    prop: {
        write: function() { ... },
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply declare prop as a property of your function.

```
var helper = new function(){
    this.prop = new function(){
       this.write = function(){
           //write the property
        }
        this.getProp = function(){
           //get property
        }
        this.updateProp = function(){
           //get property
        }
    }
};
```

Try this snippet:

```js
var helper = new function(){
    this.prop = new function(){
       this.write = function(){
           //write the property
        }
        this.getProp = function(){
           //get property
          alert("this.getProp");
        }
        this.updateProp = function(){
           //get property
        }
    }
};

helper.prop.getProp();
```

Answer (score 1):

Every function in JS returns undefined unless you explicitly return something else, in this case you should return the prop to keep the chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this ..

```
/*************************************************************/
// Modular approach to write javascript.
/*************************************************************/


var foo = (function () {
    var publicAPI = {
        bar: function () {
            publicAPI.baz();
        },
        baz: function () {
            console.log("Baz");
        }
    };

    return publicAPI;

})();

foo.bar();
```

One More approach you can follow is like this.

```
var outerObj = {};
(function(test) {
  'use strict';
  test.sayHello = function(name) {
    return 'Hi ' + name;
  }
})(outerObj);

alert(outerObj.sayHello('Kaushik'));
```